# EF many to many, when update it always insert new row in bridge table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

```
class Student{
public string Name {get; set;}

public EntityCollection<Info> Infos {get; set;}
}

class Info{
public string Title {get; set;}

public EntityCollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

//----------------

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany( u => u.Infos)
            .WithMany( c => c.Students)
            .Map( wt =>
            {
                wt.MapLeftKey( "StudentId" );
                wt.MapRightKey( "InfoId" );
                wt.ToTable( "StudentInfo" );
            } );
```

In db I have three tables (Student, Info and bridge table StudentInfo). It work as expect when insert. But when I tried to get Student entity and it Infos, I set  new Student Name and save change db context. It always insert new record into bridge table (duplicate StudentId and InfoId). How to avoid that?

Comment: Can you include the code that you use to retrieve and update the student? Based on the mappings you provided I couldn't reproduce the problem. Issues like this commonly occur if you attempt to load related collections manually rather than using .Include(). Changing a student name should work fine even without eager loading the infos.

Comment: Also what version of EF?  Normally you don't use EntityCollection, and Navigation Properties are declared as `public virtual ICollection<TEntity> Entities {get;} = new HashSet<TEntity>()`

Comment: @StevePy seem the problem cause by I load related collections manually. How to attach List of Infos (that loaded manually) into Student.Infos. If I loop though and use Student.Infos.Add it will cause the insert when save changes

Comment: An example for loading a single student where you want the infos as well: `var student = dbContext.Students.Include(x => x.Infos).SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentId == studentId);`  If you load a student then set their collection of infos after-the-fact, EF will treat that as adding new relationships resulting in duplicate records. On a side note you should set the PK on that joining table to be the StudentId + InfoId which will create a unique constraint. This would result in an exception if items added incorrectly rather than silent duplication.

Comment: @StevePy Is there any way to work around? Because the exception will stop the whole db context save changes.

Comment: See your other question. I posted the example there. There should be no need for a work-around. You're trying to do things manually where EF has already taken care of it for you. Add the .Include() and get rid of all of the code to load/populate the Infos and you should be good to go.

Comment: The problem is code in above is just example, I have 7 tables connect together and must use three different "query" to get all of it data. So I cannot use a single query